# Magnetic force on a plate by a convergent magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

Hi Physics StackExchange!

For the same research I have mentioned in my previous question, I pose another question. My initial thought was that this topic was easy to find in textbooks or other sources, yet that was not the case, or my hours of strolling the internet for sources were not exhaustive enough.

In the experiment that I am conducting, I am researching the relationship between the magnetic force due to a magnetic field imposed by a current-carrying coil on a metal object and the distance between the object and the coil. In the previous question I asked, I go into the expression of the magnetic field at a certain point on the centre axis of the coil with distance x from the coil. Now, I wish to find a way to express the magnetic force in terms of or in relation to the magnetic field. The object which is pulled down to the coil is a corner-rounded square plate, which most likely already has a major effect on the pull, however, the centre of the square is directly in the centre axis of the coil and lies perpendicular to the centre-most magnetic field line (as it converges/is non-homogeneous). So I presume a nice symmetry trick can be applied to any rotational symmetric shape, e.g. a square, circle or hexagon. The plate has thickness $\Delta x$ and width (side to side) $L$. Now suppose I have an expression for the magnetic field along the centre axis as a function of the distance from the coil, say $B(d)$. Please view my schematic below:

[[image: A convergent/non-homogeneous magnetic field B through a square plate width thickness <span class=]$\Delta x$, width L (side to side) exerting a magnetic force on said plate." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQ0OO.png)

I have read through plenty of articles, explanations and reports on magnetic forces, namely the Lorentz force, Faraday's and Lenz's law and the approximations on the Wikipedia page "Forces between magnets", though probably skimming too hastily. The time that the magnet is in proximity to the metal plate then also has an effect on the magnetization of the plate, but let's presume it has completely set (I will start measuring after a set amount of time). How can I now find the magnetic force pulling down on the plate, using the known parameters and (calculated) variables $L$, $\Delta x$, $d$ and $B(d)$? With the few clues or thoughts my professor has given, we can simplify the situation to a slight difference in the magnetic flux between the top and bottom part of the plate, being:

$$F \sim \frac{dB}{dx} \Delta x$$

Do you have any other ideas on coming to an expression, relation or approximation? Any elaboration would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!